# Is it possible to use hostgator domains on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have an application that I want to launch on AWS. This application must have a domain that would allow me to create hundreds of thousands of subdomains.

Now, Hostgator allows you to purchase a domain that you can create an unlimited number of subdomains.

Is it possible for me to transfer my subdomains created on Hostgator to AWS?

Comment: Every domain you purchase allows unlimited subdomains regardless of who its from. The place where you manage DNS could restrict that, but the registrar (the place you actually buy the domain) can not.

Comment: @jordanm Godaddy only allows you to created 500 subdomains.

Comment: That's the their restriction for their management interface, not as a registrar. Register with godaddy and then host the DNS elsewhere (AWS route53, self-managed bind9 server, etc) and you won't have that limitation

Answer (score 0):

Jordanm makes a few good points in the comments.

We need to distinguish between the registrar and the DNS provider that hosts the domain.

The registrar allows you to buy a domain, which is then registered to you and allows you to use it.
In order to use that domain, you need a name server (in practice it's more than one) that can respond to requests for that domain.
You can tell the registrar what the name servers for your domain are and for this you set the NS (short for - you guessed it - name server) records for your domain to point to your name server.

This name server can then create as many subdomains as it likes, because it will be the authoritative source for others to find these subdomains.

Many registrars also host a name server for you and some limit the number of subdomains.
If that's the case for your registrar, you can just use another DNS service and tell your registrar that the other DNS service is now responsible for your domain.

In the case of AWS, you would create a public hosted zone for your domain in Route 53.
It will then tell you, which NS records to configure with your registrar.
When you've done that, you can manage your domain and subdomain in Route53.
You can also directly buy a domain in Route 53, because AWS acts as a registrar as well.

(A little bit simplified, but that's basically the process)